# Menu.param 2 params, not compile

Tags: scala, lift, parameters

I'm around trying to understand how "Menu.param" works with 2 params

I'm using this code as an example:

https://github.com/dpp/starting_point/blob/menu_fun/src/main/scala/code/snippet/AThread.scala

But I can not make it work

```
object APost {

  // Create a menu for /user/santo
  val menu = Menu.param[( User, Posts )]("ParamId1", "ParamId2",
    {
      case User(p1) :: Posts(p2) :: Nil =>
        Full( (p1, p2) )
      case _ =>
        Empty
    },
    params => List(params._1.id.toString,params._2.id.toString)) / * / * >> LocGroup("UserPost")

  lazy val loc = menu.toLoc

  def render = "*" #> loc.currentValue.map(_.docId)

}
```

When compiling sends me the following error:

```
[error] /menu2params/src/main/scala/code/snippet/APost.scala:23: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B]
[error]  required: String
[error]     case ParamId1(p1) :: ParamId1(p2) :: Nil =>
[error]                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Someone who can help me please

Here is the copy of my project:

https://github.com/hectorgool/menu2params/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/snippet/APost.scala

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Nil` at the end of the list rather than a wildcard, as in dpp's example?

Comment: Since they are both mounting `* / *`, List is only looking for two parameters so the final argument (list v. wildcard) doesn't matter much. If he had mounted `/**` it would make a difference since dpp's example would match `/user/post/otherdata` and this code wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

`Menu.param` is for use with a single parameter, hence the error requiring a `String` instead of a `List`. `Menu.params` allows you to specify multiple parameters in a list. Making that change to your code should resolve the issue.

Comment: SOLVED!

Menu.params

Thanks for your help

The code was:

https://github.com/hectorgool/menu2params/blob/master/src/main/scala/code/snippet/APost.scala

I made some changes and it works!